# Gradle sync failed: Could not find method android() for arguments on root project on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am new to android programming, when I try to build my first project, I get the following error -

> Gradle sync failed: Could not find method android() for arguments [build_ed74sxwq3zd69j7x0p9x4y5fb$_run_closure3@3d54d64f] on root project 'MyApplication' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
}
dependencies {compile files('app/libs/junit-4.12-JavaDoc.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

The app/build/gradle file is  -

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.surabhi.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('app/libs/junit-4.12-JavaDoc.jar') }
    apply plugin: mavin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the **wrong** `build.gradle` file.

**You can't define** the `android` block in the top-level file.

You have **to remove** this part in your

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
}
dependencies {compile files('app/libs/junit-4.12-JavaDoc.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem in android studio 2.3.3, what i was doing wrong is that my dependencies were in the the wrong build.gradle (this is wrong)[image]

The build.gradle that we need is the one with the android option as in the following `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.movas.mservice12"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 11
    versionName "2.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
dexOptions {
   // incremental = true
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
}
```

}`
Ensue where you are adding the dexOptions is inside the android curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I added this to the project level gradle file. Move this to the app level gradle file and you should be good.