# Building a asset pack in a Ionic project in Android studio

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, ionic3, capacitor

I have recently converted my only **cordova** project to use **Ionic** and **Capacitor**.
Publishing to the app store I find my app is too big (in the aab format), because I have too many images.
I understand I need to create an **asset pack**.  All I can find about the details of a creating an asset pack is https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-native
(anyone have any better information?).

After following those steps, in VS Code I ...

```
 > ionic build
 > ionic capacitor build
```

Then in Android studio I do.

```
Menu | Build | Make Project
```

I get the following error:

```
Build file 'C:\code\myco-match\android\build.gradle' line: 27

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_19eh0vogqj489iczcfbatfj08$_run_closure2@69641835] on root project 'android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Line 27 is

```
android {
    assetPacks = [":species-images"]
}
```

Did I leave out a step in the build?

Am I missing something in my gradle configuration? I am not that familiar with gradle).

Did I forget something in my initial app conversion? It was my 1st cordova project converted to my 1st ionic and capacitor project.

Any ideas?

Comment: I got an error with a dash in the asset pack name as mentioned here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531814/android-studio-xml-error/44533155
don't use dashes in the pack name!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the reference in my first link above I mis-read step 2.

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-native

Reading the following stack overflow issue

[Gradle sync failed: Could not find method android() for arguments on root project on android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227017/gradle-sync-failed-could-not-find-method-android-for-arguments-on-root-projec?rq=1)

Gabriele Mariotti said the poster "using the wrong build.gradle file.
You can't define the android block in the top-level file."

Reviewing the instructions **step 4** says "In the project’s app build.gradle file"
I had incorrectly changed the **top-level** `build.gradle` file.
**Step 7** lists `build.gradle` as if you change it, but that list item ought to be `/app/build.gradle`.

Now I can build and package using android studio.